# Need to create new file from the output of while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create new file from the output of while loop .
filename contains 
1
2
3

```
import subprocess
f = open("/path/filename", "r")
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    print(line) 

    if not line:
    break
```

The above code snippet will print as:
1,
2,
3

Now my question is , i need to create new file/directory with names as 1,2,3(which are output of while loop).
I need subprocess module to do this. Please suggest me.

Comment: you just need `open("line",'w').close()`

Comment: @albin-paul What sense does make to close the file right after opening it?

Comment: @KlausD. TO just create a file called line, which is what the touch command does

Comment: @KlausD:touch will create file called line ,but my query is it should create new files with the content of the filename, while loop has iterated

Comment: Please edit your question and clarity the expected result. A sample input and result is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import subprocess

f = open("test.txt", "r")
files_list = f.readlines()
files = ", ".join(files_list).replace("\n","")
cmd = "touch {0}".format(files)
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import subprocess

f = open("/path/filename", "r")
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    print(line) 

    subprocess.call('touch {}'.format(line), shell=True) 

    if not line:
        break
```

Comment: it's throwing error as :AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

Comment: It is working for me but let me try to search it more to help you out

Comment: The subprocess.run() function only exists in Python 3.5 and newer.

Comment: i am using Python 2.7.5